# InfluxDB 2.1 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, influxdb-2

I am trying to access data of InfluxDB 2.1 from Matlab 2021. There is an API for InfluxDB v1.7: https://github.com/EnricSala/influxdb-matlab but it's not working for InfluxDB v2.1 due to several changes (databases are buckets, use of tokens and so on).

How do I access data of InfluxDB 2.1 in Matlab if I only have the the InfluxDB v 1.7 client. Do I need to upgrade something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no InfluxDB 2 client for Matlab, you can still connect to InfluxDB 2 with the client for InfluxDB 1 (as you are currently using). You just need to create a couple of additional artifacts in InfuxDB 2 to make this work. Check [this post](https://community.influxdata.com/t/unable-to-connect-v1-clients-to-influxdbv2/21630/7) for what you need to do, please.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you list the main points from the linked post, i.e. what artifacts you need to create.